# FFMPEG IP Camera streaming on Youtube

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -fflags genpts+igndts+discardcorrupt+ignidx+nobuffer -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://*************** -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/***************
```

Unfortunately this sometimes produces a few ms silence gaps and clicks in the audio which I think has to do with async (increasing the async value distorts the audio making is sound wavy). I've recorded the audio with audacity to show you what I mean:

[image: 1]

Initially I simply copied the audio stream (-c:a copy) but the sound was horribly distorted and choppy on Youtube's end.

I've played around with different parameters but nothing helped solve the problem. Does anybody know what could be causing this behavior?

Log:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-10-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[tcp @ 000000000012ea80] Starting connection attempt to X.X.X.X port XXXX
[tcp @ 000000000012ea80] Successfully connected to X.X.X.X port XXXX
[rtsp @ 000000000012e300] SDP:
v=0

o=- 2251938195 2251938195 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=Media Server

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

t=0 0

a=control:*

a=packetization-supported:DH

a=rtppayload-supported:DH

a=range:npt=now-

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96

a=control:trackID=0

a=framerate:12.000000

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAH52oFAFum4CAgKAAAH0AAAu4EIAA,aM48gAA=

a=recvonly

m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97

a=control:trackID=1

a=rtpmap:97 MPEG4-GENERIC/32000

a=fmtp:97 streamtype=5;profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3;config=1288

a=recvonly


[rtsp @ 000000000012e300] setting jitter buffer size to 0
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000000133840] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuvj420p
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://****************************************':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.041000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, left), 1280x720, 12 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 32000 Hz, mono, fltp
[tcp @ 00000000001b3100] Starting connection attempt to 216.58.208.204 port 1935
[tcp @ 00000000001b3100] Successfully connected to 216.58.208.204 port 1935
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 000000000014d580] tb:1/32000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:32000 chlayout:0x4
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000000191e40] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:fltp r:32000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:fltp r:44100Hz
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000000191e40] [SWR @ 00000000001385c0] adding 16384 audio samples of silence
    Last message repeated 3 times
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000000191e40] [SWR @ 00000000001385c0] adding 11264 audio samples of silence
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/********************':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), 1 reference frame ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, left), 1280x720 (0x0), q=2-31, 12 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.55 bitrate=   1.0kbits/s speed= 6.7x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.06 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s speed=3.68x    
frame=    1 fps=0.6 q=-1.0 size=      87kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate= 172.6kbits/s speed=2.35x    
frame=   15 fps=6.6 q=-1.0 size=     147kB time=00:00:05.29 bitrate= 227.8kbits/s speed=2.32x    
frame=   21 fps=7.5 q=-1.0 size=     168kB time=00:00:05.82 bitrate= 236.6kbits/s speed=2.08x    
frame=   25 fps=6.9 q=-1.0 size=     243kB time=00:00:06.10 bitrate= 325.9kbits/s speed=1.68x    
frame=   36 fps=8.7 q=-1.0 size=     289kB time=00:00:07.10 bitrate= 333.4kbits/s speed=1.71x    
frame=   44 fps=9.5 q=-1.0 size=     317kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate= 338.7kbits/s speed=1.65x    
frame=   49 fps=8.7 q=-1.0 size=     396kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate= 399.0kbits/s speed=1.45x    
frame=   61 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=     446kB time=00:00:09.12 bitrate= 400.5kbits/s speed=1.49x    
frame=   67 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=     470kB time=00:00:09.63 bitrate= 399.8kbits/s speed=1.45x    
frame=   73 fps=9.7 q=-1.0 size=     553kB time=00:00:10.12 bitrate= 447.5kbits/s speed=1.35x    
frame=   84 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=     601kB time=00:00:11.07 bitrate= 444.2kbits/s speed=1.37x    
frame=   90 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     624kB time=00:00:11.58 bitrate= 440.8kbits/s speed=1.35x    
frame=   96 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     646kB time=00:00:12.07 bitrate= 438.0kbits/s speed=1.33x    
frame=   98 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=     713kB time=00:00:12.19 bitrate= 479.2kbits/s speed=1.27x    
frame=  109 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     760kB time=00:00:13.11 bitrate= 474.7kbits/s speed= 1.3x    
frame=  116 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     786kB time=00:00:13.60 bitrate= 472.9kbits/s speed=1.28x    
frame=  121 fps= 10 q=-1.0 size=     872kB time=00:00:14.11 bitrate= 505.9kbits/s speed=1.21x    
frame=  132 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     916kB time=00:00:15.04 bitrate= 499.0kbits/s speed=1.21x    
frame=  143 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=     956kB time=00:00:15.97 bitrate= 490.3kbits/s speed=1.23x    
frame=  145 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1029kB time=00:00:16.13 bitrate= 522.6kbits/s speed=1.18x    
frame=  159 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1083kB time=00:00:17.22 bitrate= 514.9kbits/s speed=1.21x    
frame=  165 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1108kB time=00:00:17.74 bitrate= 511.7kbits/s speed= 1.2x    
frame=  169 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1188kB time=00:00:18.11 bitrate= 537.3kbits/s speed=1.16x    
frame=  182 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1242kB time=00:00:19.17 bitrate= 530.5kbits/s speed=1.19x    
frame=  189 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1265kB time=00:00:19.69 bitrate= 526.2kbits/s speed=1.18x    
frame=  193 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1348kB time=00:00:20.13 bitrate= 548.7kbits/s speed=1.14x    
frame=  206 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1400kB time=00:00:21.13 bitrate= 542.9kbits/s speed=1.17x    
frame=  212 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1426kB time=00:00:21.66 bitrate= 539.3kbits/s speed=1.16x    
frame=  217 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1512kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate= 559.9kbits/s speed=1.13x    
frame=  230 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1566kB time=00:00:23.17 bitrate= 553.5kbits/s speed=1.15x    
frame=  236 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1587kB time=00:00:23.66 bitrate= 549.5kbits/s speed=1.14x    
frame=  241 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1672kB time=00:00:24.10 bitrate= 568.2kbits/s speed=1.12x    
frame=  253 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1723kB time=00:00:25.12 bitrate= 561.9kbits/s speed=1.14x    
frame=  260 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1746kB time=00:00:25.61 bitrate= 558.4kbits/s speed=1.13x    
frame=  265 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1833kB time=00:00:26.14 bitrate= 574.2kbits/s speed=1.11x    
frame=  278 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    1887kB time=00:00:27.16 bitrate= 569.1kbits/s speed=1.12x    
frame=  285 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    1910kB time=00:00:27.69 bitrate= 564.9kbits/s speed=1.12x    
frame=  289 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    1993kB time=00:00:28.14 bitrate= 580.2kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
frame=  301 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2044kB time=00:00:29.11 bitrate= 574.9kbits/s speed=1.11x    
frame=  308 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2069kB time=00:00:29.67 bitrate= 571.1kbits/s speed=1.11x    
frame=  313 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    2154kB time=00:00:30.11 bitrate= 585.8kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  325 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2204kB time=00:00:31.11 bitrate= 580.3kbits/s speed=1.11x    
frame=  331 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2226kB time=00:00:31.57 bitrate= 577.4kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
frame=  337 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    2312kB time=00:00:32.13 bitrate= 589.4kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  350 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2364kB time=00:00:33.13 bitrate= 584.5kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
frame=  356 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2388kB time=00:00:33.64 bitrate= 581.5kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
frame=  362 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    2473kB time=00:00:34.13 bitrate= 593.4kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  373 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2522kB time=00:00:35.10 bitrate= 588.6kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  380 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2548kB time=00:00:35.64 bitrate= 585.5kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  386 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    2632kB time=00:00:36.12 bitrate= 596.9kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  398 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2681kB time=00:00:37.12 bitrate= 591.6kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  404 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2704kB time=00:00:37.61 bitrate= 588.9kbits/s speed=1.09x    
frame=  410 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2790kB time=00:00:38.12 bitrate= 599.5kbits/s speed=1.07x    
frame=  421 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2839kB time=00:00:39.10 bitrate= 594.8kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  427 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2861kB time=00:00:39.59 bitrate= 592.1kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  433 fps= 11 q=-1.0 size=    2947kB time=00:00:40.10 bitrate= 602.0kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  446 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    2997kB time=00:00:41.19 bitrate= 596.0kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  453 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3020kB time=00:00:41.70 bitrate= 593.2kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  458 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3103kB time=00:00:42.12 bitrate= 603.4kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  469 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3151kB time=00:00:43.12 bitrate= 598.7kbits/s speed=1.08x    
frame=  475 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3173kB time=00:00:43.58 bitrate= 596.5kbits/s speed=1.07x    
frame=  481 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3260kB time=00:00:44.09 bitrate= 605.7kbits/s speed=1.06x    
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0000000000191e40] [SWR @ 00000000001385c0] discarding 9657 audio samples
[flv @ 00000000030400c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 44682, current: 44525; changing to 44682. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 00000000030400c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 44682, current: 44605; changing to 44682. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  493 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3302kB time=00:00:44.81 bitrate= 603.6kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  500 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3329kB time=00:00:45.39 bitrate= 600.7kbits/s speed=1.07x    
frame=  505 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3412kB time=00:00:45.86 bitrate= 609.6kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  517 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3462kB time=00:00:46.85 bitrate= 605.2kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  525 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3488kB time=00:00:47.43 bitrate= 602.4kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  529 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3570kB time=00:00:47.87 bitrate= 610.9kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  542 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3620kB time=00:00:48.87 bitrate= 606.6kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  548 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3642kB time=00:00:49.38 bitrate= 604.1kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  553 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3724kB time=00:00:49.83 bitrate= 612.3kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  565 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3774kB time=00:00:50.85 bitrate= 608.0kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  571 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3797kB time=00:00:51.36 bitrate= 605.6kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  577 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3882kB time=00:00:51.82 bitrate= 613.6kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  589 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3931kB time=00:00:52.84 bitrate= 609.4kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  595 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    3951kB time=00:00:53.36 bitrate= 606.6kbits/s speed=1.06x    
frame=  601 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4038kB time=00:00:53.82 bitrate= 614.5kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  613 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4086kB time=00:00:54.86 bitrate= 610.1kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  619 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4109kB time=00:00:55.33 bitrate= 608.3kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  625 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4195kB time=00:00:55.82 bitrate= 615.6kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  637 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4243kB time=00:00:56.86 bitrate= 611.2kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  644 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4267kB time=00:00:57.37 bitrate= 609.3kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  649 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4350kB time=00:00:57.84 bitrate= 616.1kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  661 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4400kB time=00:00:58.79 bitrate= 613.1kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  667 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4421kB time=00:00:59.30 bitrate= 610.7kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  672 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4439kB time=00:00:59.79 bitrate= 608.2kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  674 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4512kB time=00:00:59.90 bitrate= 616.9kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  686 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4560kB time=00:01:00.92 bitrate= 613.1kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  692 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4580kB time=00:01:01.44 bitrate= 610.7kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  697 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4664kB time=00:01:01.83 bitrate= 617.9kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  708 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4711kB time=00:01:02.78 bitrate= 614.6kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  715 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4737kB time=00:01:03.27 bitrate= 613.3kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  721 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4822kB time=00:01:03.80 bitrate= 619.1kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  733 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4872kB time=00:01:04.87 bitrate= 615.2kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  741 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4898kB time=00:01:05.38 bitrate= 613.7kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  745 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    4979kB time=00:01:05.80 bitrate= 619.8kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  757 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5029kB time=00:01:06.75 bitrate= 617.1kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  763 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5051kB time=00:01:07.26 bitrate= 615.1kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  768 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5069kB time=00:01:07.75 bitrate= 612.8kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  770 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5141kB time=00:01:07.87 bitrate= 620.5kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  781 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5187kB time=00:01:08.80 bitrate= 617.6kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  788 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5209kB time=00:01:09.35 bitrate= 615.2kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  793 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5293kB time=00:01:09.79 bitrate= 621.3kbits/s speed=1.03x    
frame=  804 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=    5340kB time=00:01:10.72 bitrate= 618.5kbits/s speed=1.04x
```

Comment: Show the **complete** log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: ffmpeg log added.